# How to get Visual Studio 22 to word wrap in the Test Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

In Visual Studio 2022, word-wrap is turned off by default in the `Test Explorer` window/`Test Detail Summary` pane.  This makes viewing the tests difficult because of scrolling horizontally.

**How do I turn word-wrap back on in the `Test Explorer` window?**

Comment: Couldn't find this question/answer anywhere, so just sharing the solution now that I've found it

Answer (score 6):

I am running Visual Studio 2022 (v17.0.6), just right-click on the `Test Detail Summary` pane in the Test Explorer window and choose `Wrap Text in Summary Pane`.

Comment: Make sure that you are clicking on the actual text in the Test Detail Summary pane - right-clicking in the blank area below it does nothing!